# MVVM dependency property not passing value to viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ViewModel with two properties:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, sets the start datetime
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime StartDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return startDateTime;
        }

        set
        {
            if (startDateTime == value) {
                return;
            }
            startDateTime = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("StartDateTime");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, sets the end datetime
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime EndDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return endDateTime;
        }

        set
        {
            if (endDateTime == value) {
                return;
            }
            endDateTime = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("EndDateTime");
        }
    }
```

In my View I have a control like this:

```
 <controls:WinFormsWrapper EndDateTime="{Binding EndDateTime, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                           StartDateTime="{Binding StartDateTime, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

My `WinFormsWrapper` has two dependency properties like this:

```
/// <summary>
    /// The dependency property for StartDateTime
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartDateTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StartDateTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(WinFormsWrapper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(control.StartDateTime, new PropertyChangedCallback(StartDateTime_Changed)));

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">The arguments</param>
    private static void StartDateTime_Changed(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        control.SetDateTimeStartValue((DateTime)e.NewValue, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, sets the StartDateTime
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime StartDateTime
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(StartDateTimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartDateTimeProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The dependency property for EndDateTime
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndDateTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EndDateTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(WinFormsWrapper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(control.EndDateTime, new PropertyChangedCallback(EndDateTime_Changed)));

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">The arguments</param>
    private static void EndDateTime_Changed(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        control.SetDateTimeEndValue((DateTime)e.NewValue, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets, sets the EndDateTime
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime EndDateTime
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(EndDateTimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EndDateTimeProperty, value); }
    }
```

For some reason now the `StartDateTime` property is changed within my viewmodel when I change the datetime in the gui, but the `EndDateTime` not (In the `WinFormsWrapper` class both properties are set correct). Can anyone give me a hint why is that?

EDIT:

After some analysis, I think there might be a problem with this event:

My `WinFormsWrapper : WinFormsHost` inherits from WinFormsHost. The Forms control hosted has a `CurrentTimeChanged` Event and in the constructor of my `WinFormsHost` I am registering this event:

```
public WinFormsWrapper()
    {
        this.Child = control;           

        control.CurrentTimeChanged += control_CurrentTimeChanged;
    }
```

Then when this event fires I do:

```
void control_CurrentTimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EndDateTime = ((EtDateTimeRange)sender).EndDateTime;            
        StartDateTime = ((EtDateTimeRange)sender).StartDateTime;
    }
```

And it seems like whatever property I set first (`EndDateTime` or `StartDateTime`), is passed to my VM, and the other one isn't.

Comment: Everything you've shown us looks fine to me. Could you show some of the relevant xaml for "WinFormsWrapper"? I'm wondering if the textbox or whatever is bound incorrectly in the control itself.

Comment: are there any bindings error in output window?

Comment: Your problem is *not* demonstrated by your displayed code. Please edit your question and provide a [complete, but concise, working example of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know debugging these things can be hard, but can you at least trace the flow and know what gets change and when? There is certainly nothing obvious on the code you've revealed.

Comment: I will on monday, cant access the code right now, sorry.